# Laravel form unexpected 'namespace'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to do a basic form and I did that 1 week ago but this time I have a new bug surely a stupid mistake but...

So here is my UsersController

```html
<?php
  
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  
class UsersController extends Controller
      
      
{
    public function getInfos()
          
          
    {
        return view('infos');
    }
      
      
    public function postInfos(Request $request)
    {
        return 'His name ' . $request->input('firstname');
 
    }
}
```

My infos.blade

```html
@extends('template')

@section('contenu')
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'users']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('frstname', 'Your name : ') !!}
        {!! Form::text('firstanme') !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Send !') !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

And the web.php

```html
Route::get('users', 'UsersController@getInfos');
Route::post('users', 'UsersController@postInfos');
```

I use a template but I'm almost sure that's not the problem , I think I do bad routing , I have this error message

> syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_NAMESPACE)

Thx to help me :)

ps : the error message [image]

Comment: This is not the answer but you have a typo in your code ```Form::text('firstanme')``` should be "firstname"

Comment: {!! Form::text('firstanme') !! is this a typo??

Comment: Php version? Just checkin'

Comment: Also, can you please show the full error message?

Comment: check probably related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592425/is-starting-route-grouping-with-namespace-not-allowed-in-laravel-5-4

Comment: So I use
  "php": "^7.1.3" and 
  "laravel/framework": "5.8.*"

Comment: I change to firstname but nothing change

Comment: please check my answer below, you have a few spelling mistakes, and a few form errors

Comment: Could you show the full error message?

Comment: Also, please show your full web.php. It could be related to Alex's dupe, but without information, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Thibaudkhan `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` not needed at all. Which line is causing you `syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_NAMESPACE)`? Post the complete log.

Comment: The full error message 
"Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE)
syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_NAMESPACE)" and namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: `composer update` ?

Comment: What version of PHP do you have? Namespaces were introduced in PHP 5.3.

Comment: I have php 7.1.3

Comment: I only have that in my web.php Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@getInfos')->name('users.get');
Route::post('/users', 'UsersController@postInfos')->name('users.post');


Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'WelcomeController@index', 'as' => 'home']);

Comment: composer update doesn't resolve this problem

Comment: Maybe I need to write something different in url ( http://localhost:8000/users)

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a bad invisible character somewhere. Try deleting the first 3 lines and retyping them.

Comment: what is your host OS? do you use xamp or other windows bundles? apache? nginx?

Comment: I use wamp  with apache 2.4

Comment: @Thibaudkhan If you replace `public/index.php` with `<?php echo phpversion();` does it output 7.1? It's not uncommon to have multiple PHP versions on a server.

Answer (score -1):

Since ypur namespace suggests the said controller resides in the same directory as the extended controller you dont need to specify this.

Also depending on the laravel version you may require running

```
php artisan dump:autoload
```